Building an attachment from the edge of a Mesh
I am noobie for blender. I am working on a Mesh. Like ,I have a blender model which has subdiv modifier applied. now i want to extract the boundary and build an extension like part from it. Its a boat hull. High quality mesh. Because of the Improper Topology, the edges are not getting selected as edge loop. How do i extract the edge and build a new object from it. I basically come from Nurbs / Surfacing background. So my thinking is in surface modeling style. If there is a better idea , please suggest me.Any help would be highly appreciated 

“Extract the boundary and build an extension like part from it”? Idk what that means, but from other context I take it you want to select the edge loop of something. Without showing exactly what topology you’re working with (no, the unlabeled and tightly cropped screenshot of idk what in the bottom won’t do), it is impossible to say how to select whatever loop you are dealing with.

Hello do you have some images of the hull you're trying to achieve? It would help to understand

@TheLabCat   Added one more Image for you reference. Say i want to build a attachment that is exactly on the Top edge of the Hull. So you dont see a crack or gap in rendering. And also say i want to build an attachment glass that i put on top of the hull in the side view. This glass should be exactly siting on the hull. How to do these two?. Thankyou for your reply.

First, that information should be in the question directly. Second, I can still only see one side of the boat, not the top or the back.
